# GCD dispatch_async DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I want to write log to a file in global default queue. It works well in iOS 6 but crash in iOS 5 even if the block is empty.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
//fprintf(s_logfp, "[%s] %s\n", [[[NSDate date] hipuClientLogDescription] UTF8String], [log UTF8String]);
});
```

It goes all right if my code is like this:

```
logQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.hipu.clientlog", NULL);
dispatch_async(logQueue, ^{
    fprintf(s_logfp, "[%s] %s\n", [[[NSDate date] hipuClientLogDescription] UTF8String], [log UTF8String]);
});
```

Call stack:

```
#0  0x01dff0b0 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x01dffd40 in objc_retain ()
#2  0x0044a712 in HpWriteLogToDisk at /Users/tanqiyu/Documents/hipu_work/iOS/trunk/HipuClient/HpFoundation/HpFoundation/HpLog.m:60
#3  0x003420b6 in -[HpEngine initWithRootDir:appVersion:] at /Users/tanqiyu/Documents/hipu_work/iOS/trunk/HipuClient/HpEngine/HpEngine/Engine/HpEngine.m:69
#4  0x00341a8d in +[HpEngine initEngineWithRootDir:appVersion:] at /Users/tanqiyu/Documents/hipu_work/iOS/trunk/HipuClient/HpEngine/HpEngine/Engine/HpEngine.m:28
#5  0x0000abcd in -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] at /Users/tanqiyu/Documents/hipu_work/iOS/trunk/HipuClient/HipuClient/HipuClient/AppDelegate.m:35
#6  0x00f5a9d6 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] ()
#7  0x00f5b8a6 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] ()
#8  0x00f6a743 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] ()
#9  0x00f6b1f8 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#10 0x00f5eaa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#11 0x02325fa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#12 0x021661c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#13 0x020cb022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#14 0x020c990a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#15 0x020c8db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#16 0x020c8ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#17 0x00f5b2a7 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#18 0x00f5ca9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#19 0x0000a97d in main at
```

Comment: Post the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{}); works for me

Comment: rob-mayoff, I have posted the call stack, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes with no code in the block you are surely corrupting memory.

When you fix that:

1) insure that slogfp is a global and does not change.

2) if either string is nil you will crash trying to use a char* which is nil. Suggest you create one NSString first, test its valid, only then dispatch it for logging.